# branch.io bypass of app login screen, how to handle delay before url handled

Tags: ios, sdk, branch.io

I am using branch.io SDK in an ios App.  We use it as a way to invite users to our app, and redirect them to a custom on-boarding screen when the branch link is present.  One thing we've noticed is that there is a slight delay between when the app opens and when branch's handler is called.

What this means is that my app loads it's usual start screen, and then maybe half a second later branch's code is run and my app redirects to the correct view.  I see the LaunchScreen, my Login Screen for half a second, then my branch.io handler view.  All that is correct, but I'm wondering how to better structure this so that there isn't the initial Login Screen View?

There is also the possibility of a race condition with the branch block and the normal app's startup blocks-- both of which are async.  Right now the branch block always takes longer, so not a big deal.

Some ideas I had:

1) Create an initial View similar to the LaunchScreen that the app lands on until branch.io returns, artificially extending the splash screen instead of showing a Login Screen.  The problem here is that this also requires Branch.io to trigger the non-branch.io continuation, and means a half second delay for all entries.  Not good.  If I need a network call in addition, the delay could be longer, a spinner doesn't help this process.

2) Embed the AuthManager login state code within the branch.io handler, such that the normal app process runs serially to the branch; instead of both running async.  Once again, this creates a delay that must be handled, else there is just a white screen for half a second.  It also ties my entire app's loading success to branch.io's SDK working as expected, not what I prefer to rely on for any SDK.

Is there a better way to architect this workflow?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
   //...

   // initialize branch.io
   Branch *branch = [Branch getInstance];
   [branch initSessionWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions andRegisterDeepLinkHandler:^(NSDictionary *params, NSError *error) {
      // do stuff with branch, such as redirect to a custom View.
      // run every load and handled if branch.io link present     

      // possible network call(s) involved if branch link present.     
   }];

   // ...

   [[AuthManager sharedInstance] isLoggedInCompletionHandler:^{
      // load HomeViewController (logged in)
   } notLoggedInCompletionHandler:^{
      // load LoginViewController (not logged in)
   }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alex with Branch.io here:

This slight delay is a unavoidable limitation waiting for data from a server callback. Branch does everything possible to make the wait as short as we can, and when trying to resolve this situation, our partners have often taken an approach similar to your second idea.

The Branch callback is guaranteed to fire 100% of the time (even when the network is out) so the best option is to build a splash screen that basically holds *all routing* until the callback arrives. If Branch gives nothing, you can route regularly. If Branch gives something, you can route to the deep linked content.